# Copying entire XML file while changing some properties

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the XML file:

```
<libros>
  <libro>
    <titulo>El Hobbit</titulo>
    <autor>J. R. Tolkien</autor>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>La colmena</titulo>
    <autor>C. J. Cela</autor>
  </libro>
  <libro>
    <titulo>Guerra y Paz</titulo>
    <autor>León Tolstoi</autor>
  </libro>
</libros>
```

What the XSL must do is: take the label "autor" and place it inside "libro" as attribute, something like this:

```
<libro autor="León Tolstoi">
   <titulo>Guerra y Paz</titulo>
</libro>
```

As far as I could get is this:

```
<xsl:template match="libros">
 <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="libro">
            <xsl:attribute name="autor">
                <xsl:value-of select="//libro[1]/autor/text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="//libro[1]/titulo/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="libro">
            <xsl:attribute name="autor">
                <xsl:value-of select="//libro[2]/autor/text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="//libro[2]/titulo/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="libro">
            <xsl:attribute name="autor">
                <xsl:value-of select="//libro[3]/autor/text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="//libro[3]/titulo/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is as it must be, however I see a problem in this, what happens when i have A LOT of "libro" elements? Googleing around I've found this to copy entire document, but I haven't found the right way to edit it for my needs:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with the identity template - that will indeed copy the whole input document to the output as-is, but the point of doing it this way rather than with a single `<xsl:copy-of select="/"/>` is that you can override the identity template for specific nodes that you want to handle differently.  You don't "edit" the identity template itself, rather you add additional templates alongside it for the special cases.  In your case you need to

- add an extra `autor` attribute to `libro` elements and
- suppress the `autor` *element* completely.

For the first of these you need a template like

```
<xsl:template match="libro">
  <!-- {} is an "attribute value template" - an XPath expression rather than a
       literal string -->
  <libro autor="{autor}">
    <!-- continue processing all children as normal -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </libro>
</xsl:template>
```

and for the second you need an empty "do-nothing" template - when you encounter an `autor` element, replace it with nothing

```
<xsl:template match="autor" />
```

Here is the complete stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="libro">
    <libro autor="{autor}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </libro>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="autor" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking for this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="libro">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="autor">
            <xsl:value-of select="autor"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="titulo"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: is it a MUST to use 2 templates? Cant you do it with only 1?

Comment: @Alpha2k There are many ways to achieve the same result with XSLT. When traversing nodes, many times a recursive approach is simpler and more efficient. If you are limited to one template, you many times have to define variables, use for-each loops and choose/if blocks, that can make the stylesheet longer, less efficient and harder to read. Recursive templates aren't that complex. The time and effort to learn how to use them is worth it!